# dnf and yum: can not find package

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum

As i run these commands to install any packages with yum or dnf:

```
> sudo -c 'yum(or dnf) install [package name]'    
> sudo yum(or dnf) install [package name]
```

I get this error:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:34 ago on Thu 05 Jul 2018 12:27:36 AM +0430.    
No match for argument: [package name]    
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Any solution?

Comment: what repositories do you have enabled? is it a package from epel?

Comment: @thebtm  i don't know.i haven't touch anything but i'm sure the packages are available.

Comment: `yum repolist` will display the active repo list, I suspect the packages your looking for are not in the base/update/extras repositories and you may need to add additional repositories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yum repolist` will display the active repo list, I suspect the packages your looking for are not in the base/update/extras repositories and you may need to add additional repositories.

A good way to find out is to google search the package your looking for to get an idea of repository you need to have setup or install.

A lot of repositories do have a RPM file that will install the repository for your or a "how to" for adding the repository.

#### Examples below

Red Hat has made the documentation free to read 
[9.5.2. Setting [repository] Options](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-configuring_yum_and_yum_repositories#sec-Setting_repository_Options)

IUS repo setup
[IUS Getting Started](https://ius.io/GettingStarted/)

`yum repolist` example:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.its.sfu.ca
 * extras: mirror.it.ubc.ca
 * updates: centos.mirror.rafal.ca
base                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                                                                                | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                                                                               | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
(1/4): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                                                                                                                                         | 166 kB  00:00:00     
(2/4): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                     | 150 kB  00:00:00     
(3/4): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.6 MB  00:00:00     
(4/4): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                                                                                                                                       | 5.9 MB  00:00:01     
repo id                                                                                                           repo name                                                                                                            status
base/7/x86_64                                                                                                     CentOS-7 - Base                                                                                                      9911
extras/7/x86_64                                                                                                   CentOS-7 - Extras                                                                                                     314
updates/7/x86_64                                                                                                  CentOS-7 - Updates                                                                                                    946
repolist: 11171
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `yum search packageName` ?

I have seen similar behavior from two other causes, DNS is not working or the cache is corrupted.

On that machine can you ping a host by name? i.e. `ping google.com` ?

If that works, try a `yum clean all` and then try to install your package when it is done.

Comment: yes, actually i didn't know fedoras repositories does not support some packages which ubuntu does. searched and found that there's a RPM Fusion which support those packages (like MPV or Mocp) and need to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue and observed the following instructions after installing node:

```
curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
sudo dnf install yarn
```

Check installation with

```
yarn -v
```

Comment: Can you update this answer? It's 2023 and it's not working anymore